# How I can use a contextual action mode for recyclerview inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-recyclerview

Hey I have a problem with contextual action mode in my android app. I have a TaskActivity (AppCompatActivity) and inside three tabs. All tabs are Fragments. In my first tab TaskOwnListTabFragment (Fragment) i have this layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listview_task_tasklist_ownlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inside my Adapter I  handle the onLOngPressed Event. My RecyclerView will be fill by a adapter:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater _inflater, ViewGroup _container, Bundle _savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.d(TAG,":TaskOwnListTabFragment.onCreateView()");

    View view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_task_ownlist, _container, false);

    this.taskList = Task.createDummyTasksList(10); // Es werden Dummy Daten geladen

    this.recyclerViewOwnTasks = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_task_tasklist_ownlist);
    this.recyclerViewOwnTasks.setAdapter(new TaskOwnListAdapter(this.taskList));
    this.recyclerViewOwnTasks.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));


    return view;
}
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class TaskOwnListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskOwnListAdapter.TaskOwnListViewHolder>
{
    private static final String TAG = "familyplan.debug";

    private List<Task> TaskList = null;

    public TaskOwnListAdapter(List<Task> _taskList)
    {
        this.TaskList = _taskList;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskOwnListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_task, parent, false);
        return new TaskOwnListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskOwnListViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Task task = this.TaskList.get(position); //Ausgewählte Aufgabe wird zurückgegeben

        final TextView textViewTaskName = holder.textViewTaskName;
        final TextView textViewTaskDescription = holder.textViewTaskDescription;

        textViewTaskName.setText(task.getTaskName());
        textViewTaskDescription.setText(task.getTaskDescription());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,":TaskOwnListAdapter.onClick() -> item with value = " + textViewTaskName.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,":TaskOwnListAdapter.onLongClick()");
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return this.TaskList.size();
    }

    public class TaskOwnListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView textViewTaskName;
        public TextView textViewTaskDescription;

        public TaskOwnListViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTaskName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_task_name);
            textViewTaskDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_task_description);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how I can use the CAB inside my Fragment for my case :( if everyone has a idea then please help me.

Comment: Let the activity handle it

Comment: i use a tablayout with three fragments. my question is how i can use the  contextual action mode in a fragment not in a activity ;)

Comment: I get that. My advice stands

Comment: but this is no answer to my question just an alternative to the problem. I would have to adjust much in my app then and change some structures. this can not be the solution. you can certainly use a fragment.

Comment: A fragment is a partial view that has no toolbar of its own. The managing activity does. Therefore it is the activity's responsibility to manage the toolbar and its state. You can communicate from the fragment to the activity to let it know that you want the toolbar to go in CAB mode, but you should not (try to) update the toolbar directly from within the fragment

Comment: that was ever a small help in the right direction. So I can tell about the fragment of the activity I want to change now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154329/discussion-between-tarasov-and-tim-castelijns).